# Unable to edit file using lineinfile Ansible module

Tags: file, permissions, ansible, line, edit

I'm trying to add a line `export TMOUT=50000` to a file `/backup/backup.sh` using Ansible.

Below is my playbook:

```
   - name: Add Timeout Entry if not present
     lineinfile:
       path: "/backup/backup.sh"
       insertbefore: BOF
       state: present
       line: 'export TMOUT=50000'
```

Getting the below error for ansible playbook:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 18] Cannot link to a file on another device.: b'/tmp/tmphtvszlfc' -> b'/wd/backup.sh'
fatal: [10.9.16.133]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The destination directory (/wd) is not writable by the current user. Error was: [Errno 13] The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.: b'/wd/.ansible_tmp3yhi8j7bbackup.sh'"}
```

Below is the drive information of the target server:

```
df -k
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4          6291456   3323144   48%    42948     6% /
/dev/hd2          6684672   3028820   55%    54304     8% /usr
/dev/hd9var      15728640    810228   95%    13874     7% /var
/dev/hd3          6422528   1856680   72%     4035     1% /tmp
/proc                   -         -    -         -     -  /proc
/dev/wdlv        55574528  30603740   45%   315925     5% /wd
/dev/dcclv       37748736  10042348   74%   364803    14% /dcc
/dev/userslv      1048576   1039616    1%       59     1% /users
10.9.9.105:/ifs/data/NAS_RMANBKP 418298160992 14912895200   97% 589129885906    94% /backup
10.9.12.25:/ORACLE_1 32212254720 9509599696   71%      706     1% /ORACLE_1
```

The file is definately editable:

```
/wd>ls -ltr /wd/backup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 user1  dba             173 Apr 05 17:15 /wd/backup.sh

/wd>ls -lad /wd
drwxr-xr-x    1 root  system             173 Apr 05 17:15 /wd/backup.sh
```

Kindly suggest how can I overcome the issue?

Comment: Can you share output of command 'ls -la' basically, I want to see the permission on directory /wd

Comment: Updated the original post with ls -lad output

Comment: Are you executing completely on localhost? if so can you add connection: local just below hosts: <hosts> line or add --connection=local on commandline

Comment: No @Uttam this is being executed on a remote host.

Comment: Okay, finally, maybe look if this applies to you, I'm not sure otherwise. https://www.unix.com/aix/160906-cannot-link-file-another-device.html

Comment: Sure, @Uttam but there is no solution per se on that link.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is explicit: the user cannot write into the directory of the file, `/wd`; you can even see that in your `ls` output: `drwxr-xr-x    1 root  system` says the directory is `w`-ritable only by `root`

The fix is very simple: add `become: yes` to your task, to enable privilege escalation when running that lineinfile task:

```
  - name: Add Timeout Entry if not present
    become: yes
    lineinfile:
       path: "/backup/backup.sh"
       insertbefore: BOF
       state: present
       line: 'export TMOUT=50000'
```

Comment: I get the message "missing sudo password" @mdaniel. I don't have root password. I guess I need to elevate privileges for user1 on each target host. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right; but be aware that ansible is only for automating things, so can you edit that file by hand as `user1`, and if so what mechanism do you use to do that?

Comment: I simply use the vi editor for editing that file if I m not using ansible.